# Изменить при смене разрешения container на container-fluid

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Как при определенных размерах использовать container(в bootstrap), а при меньших(телефоны, читалки, планшеты) - container-fluid?

Нужно при больших разрешениях использовать отступы по бокам страницы, а при маленьких - их сносить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще то можно создать например такие классы при разных разрешениях как делает `bootstrap`, и дать эти классы блокам так как вам нужно:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    no-padding-xs{
        padding: 0;
    }
    no-margin-xs{
        margin: 0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
    no-padding-sm{
        padding: 0;
    }
    no-margin-sm{
        margin: 0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1199px){
    no-padding-md{
        padding: 0;
    }
    no-margin-md{
        margin: 0;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    no-padding-lg{
        padding: 0;
    }
    no-margin-lg{
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

А то что вы хотите резные классы для разных разрешениях, это только на `js` можно сделать, и то это плохой вариант.

Comment: Получается, что такой подход практикуют все в фронтенде?Я просто не верю, что я первый сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, а соответственно должно же быть готовое решение.

Comment: @nrjshka Вообще то готовое решение может быть , и это не изменение классов как вы хотели, а просто надо вообще менять структуру `html`, я так думаю, и еще не кто не говорил что если используешь `bootstrap` то  `css` не надо вообще написать кроме этого.

Comment: И дело не совсем в классах, мне нужно решение, а не зависимость от классов. Я хочу, чтобы была боковая прослойка при больших разрешениях, а при маленьких - она удалялась, хотя контент оставался тем же, но без бокового тиснения. Если не очень понятно объяснил могу добавить фотографию.

Comment: Если есть пример как это можно решить - очень прошу.
Я просто привел пример того, как это в теории можно решить, но может есть и другие подходы(должны быть):)

Comment: @nrjshka я не понимаю чем не устраивает такое решение? если бы такие классы как в ответе залили в `bootstrap` вы бы сказали классно, есть готовое решение, а чем это не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

div class="container-lg"

При остальных значениях, будет fluid

В шоке от того что за бредни предлагают вытворить